# How do I stop CMake from searching for a file I removed from my dependencies entirely?

Tags: cmake

I used to have a file called `game/test.dae` in my current CMake project. It was used in an `add_custom_command` call as a dependency.

I removed this file as a dependency from my CMakeLists.txt quite some time ago, but for some reason, my windows build environment hasn't gotten the memo (it works on macOS, though):

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '..\game\test.dae'
```

I keep running into this for old dependencies whenever I remove them in this one particular project, on windows only, and it seems the only 'fix' is to delete my build directory and start over - which is incredibly inconvenient, as I use some third-party libraries that can take up to 10 mins. to build.

Is there any way to force CMake to forget this file was ever a dependency *without* purging all my cmake files, cache, binaries, etc?

Comment: You probably removed the custom command, but didn't remove mentions of this file in other targets.

Comment: @arrowd nope, it's nowhere in my targets - if I purge the build directory, all goes well until I end up having to remove a similar dependency. (Not forgetting to rebuild the cmake cache either, btw)

Comment: Hum, what if you remove every `Makefile` in the build dir?

Comment: @arrowd ah yep, nuking the Makefiles reset it forcibly while keeping my external library builds intact

Comment: Something like `cmake --build C:/foo/build/ --target clean` is usually sufficient to delete the dep files that are created during the build process.

Answer (score -1):

While it looks like a bug in CMake, it can be worked around by deleting every `Makefile` in the build directory.

On Unix-like it can be achieved with `find build -name Makefile -delete`.